# What does the --gpu-architecture (-arch) flag of NVCC do?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I am a beginner at CUDA and I encountered a somewhat confusing behavior of NVCC when trying out this simple "hello world from gpu" example:

```
// hello_world.cu

#include <cstdio>
__global__ void hello_world() {
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    printf("hello world from thread %d\n", i);
}

int main() {
    hello_world<<<1, 10>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("Execution ends\n");
}
```

If compiled with

```bash
nvcc hello_world.cu
```

the output is:

```bash
hello world from thread 0
hello world from thread 1
hello world from thread 2
hello world from thread 3
hello world from thread 4
hello world from thread 5
hello world from thread 6
hello world from thread 7
hello world from thread 8
hello world from thread 9
Execution ends
```

However, if compiled with:

```bash
nvcc hello_world.cu -arch=sm_86
```

Then the output is only

```bash
Execution ends
```

I thought `-arch=sm_86` was only to specify the compute architecture, but it seems to change the behavior of the program as well. Why?

I am using RTX2060 and NVCC 11.1.

---

A note: This is exercise 1-4 from *Professional CUDA C Programming* by John Cheng et al., which asks the reader to see what happens when the program is compiled with/without the `-arch` flag.

Comment: @wohlstad I am using RTX2060. Thanks for the suggestion. There was indeed an error `cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice (209)`. Using `-arch=sm_75` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-arch` flag of NVCC controls the **minimum** [**compute capability**](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability) that your program will require from the GPU in order to run properly.

As you can see [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-eu/geforce/graphics-cards/compare/?section=compare-20), **RTX 2060 compute capabilty** is **7.5** (i.e. `sm_75`).
This means that it will not be able to run with higher capabilty (like `sm_86`).

You can use `-arch=sm_75` to specify this compute capability to NVCC.

You can use [`cudaGetLastError`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__ERROR.html) to check if there was an error launching the kernel.